# How do I create a running sum for the count of the number of items associated with a value in a query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to use a query to create a Bill of Materials list that gives an item number to a material. I have a column for Material and BOMPart. The Material column gives a list of item numbers that repeat for each item in the Bill of Materials. The BOMPart column lists each part of the item in Material. So Material 1 is created using items a, b, and c. I would like the third column, ItemNo, to start at 1 for each Material and count each BOMPart associated to the material. It should then reset to 1 for the next Material. Any suggestions? I am still pretty new to Access. Here is what I would like the columns to look like, I replaced my actual material numbers for simplicity.

| Material | BOMPart | ItemNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 |
| 1 | c | 3 |
| 2 | a | 1 |
| 2 | f | 2 |
| 3 | g | 1 |
| 3 | h | 2 |
| 3 | i | 3 |
| 4 | k | 1 |
| 4 | m | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

You want to use row_number for this. I am not certain this works in Access.

```
select Material
   ,    BOMPart
   ,    Row_Number() over (partition by Material order by BOMPart)
from xxxx
```

Comment: Access does not have a row_number() function. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: I've only gotten something like this in Access by creating a public VBA function that saves the previous Material value and checks it to return 1 or previous + 1.  Call that function in your query.